Schottky's Theorem and the closed unit disk
Recall Schottky's Theorem:

There exists a function $\psi : (0, 1) \times (0, \infty) \to (0, \infty)$ such that for any $f$ analytic on $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$ with $\vert f(0) \vert \leq \omega$ that does not assume $0$ or $1$ as values in $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$, we have $\vert f(z) \vert \leq \psi(\theta, \omega)$ for $\vert z \vert \leq \theta$.

Here $\mathbb{D}$ denotes the open unit disk in $\mathbb{C}$ and $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$ its closure.
Every version of this theorem I find in literature${}^*$ always requires $f$ to be analytic on $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$. Why is $\mathbb{D}$ not sufficient here? Is there a counterexample?

$(*)$ For example Remmert's "Classical Topics in Complex Function Theory", or chapter 2 of Segal's "Nine Introductions in Complex Analysis.

Schottky's theorem holds for functions which are “just” holomorphic in the open unit disk $\Bbb D$ and do not take the values $0$ and $1$.
This can be seen by applying your version of Schottky's theorem to the functions $f_r(z) = f(rz)$.
There is also a quantitative version of Schottky's theorem, proven by the great Lars Ahlfors:

If $f$ is holomorphic in the open unit disk and does not take the values $0$ and $1$ then
$$
 \log |f(z)|\leq {\frac {1+\theta}{1-\theta}}(7+\max(0,\log |f(0)|))
$$
for $ |z| \le \theta < 1$.

References:

Ahlfors, Lars V. “An Extension of Schwarz’s Lemma.” Transactions of the American Mathematical Society 43, no. 3 (1938): 359–64. https://doi.org/10.2307/1990065.
Wikipedia: Schottky's theorem


That makes sense. So the versions for $\mathbb{C}$ and $\overline{\mathbb{C}}$ are equivalent?
When you say quantitative, you just mean that the bound is explicitely given, right?

The versions for $\Bbb D$ and $\overline{\Bbb D}$ are equivalent. And yes, that is what I meant.

My bad, of course I meant $\mathbb{D}$.
